# Updated Clusternodes in seperate cluster

Tags: ignite

We want to integrate Apache Ignite in our application. Our application is deployed on multiple servers on our customer networks and is able to update itself.

The problem is that while the application is updating we have servers running with different versions at the same time. Therefore the updated servers rejoin the cluster and get a copy of the data based on old classes. While all servers are updated the data gets handed around and we end up with a cluster of updated servers and old data.

My goal is to form a new empty cluster with the updated servers. I allready read that there are multiple options to do this like changing the multicast group or the localPort. But I need a solution that works for Multicast and direct IP connections and doesn't change the ports. Changing the ports can be a problem because of firewall restrictions.

I wonder if it is somehow possible to filter the nodes provided by the ipFinder and check if they are the same version.

Answer (score 3):

I think you have several options:

1. you can deactivate your cluster before the update and activate this only when last app instance is updated(https://apacheignite.readme.io/docs/baseline-topology#section-cluster-activation-tool)
2. destroy caches and create them again when last app instance is updated
3. you can set node attribute( set app version for example ) and cache filter, so new version will use a new cache which stores data only on nodes with attribute "version 4", while previous one stores data only on nodes with "version 3", so when all instances will be updated there will be no nodes with attribute "version 3" and only caches for new version will survive and store data on nodes "version 4".
   ( https://ignite.apache.org/releases/latest/javadoc/org/apache/ignite/configuration/CacheConfiguration.html#getNodeFilter-- )
   However, in this case, you need to use new cache names for each new app version.

Comment: Thanks for you ideas.
1.) I'm embedding ignite, so the bat/sh scripts don't work I think. Also I can't find a "deactivate" in the code.
2.) regually checking if the cluster has mixed versions and if this is the case destroying all caches when is resolved seems possible. But I fear that this approach runs into problems with services and peer classloading in general.
3.) Nice idea. I think is adaptable also for other thinks like services or messaging but if you ever forget to append the version to a name you have a problem.

Comment: I hope that there is a more transparent solution that doesn't require versioned names.